# bash dot . in group []

Tags: regex, bash

I wanted the ability to quickly go from a directory to one of its ancestors with name matching specific regex. I figured out that I can use `expr match` to select a specific part of the `pwd` and then `cd` inside. Then I would add a simple script as alias in `.bashrc` and call it a day.
Basically, I had to select `.../WoRd*/` from something like `/some/directory/path/WoRd.to-match_x/hello/world/`.

So I have written a regexp to do it - `'\(.*/[wW][oO][rR][dD][a-zA-Z0-9_-.]*/\)'` - but it didn't work. It selected whole string instead of the part with ".../WorD/".

```
$ str="/some/directory/path/WoRd.to-match_x/hello/world/"
$ echo "match: " $(expr match "$str" '\(.*/[wW][oO][rR][dD][a-zA-Z0-9_-.]*/\)');
match:  /some/directory/path/WoRd.to-match_x/hello/world/
```

Then I tried to mask a dot, which didn't help:

```
$ echo "match: " $(expr match "$str" '\(.*/[wW][oO][rR][dD][a-zA-Z0-9_-\.]*/\)');
match:  /some/directory/path/WoRd.to-match_x/hello/world/
```

An hour or so of googling and reading regex manuals didn't help.

I actually managed to make this thing work by moving a dot to the left:

```
$ echo "match: " $(expr match "$str" '\(.*/[wW][oO][rR][dD][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*/\)');
match:  /some/directory/path/WoRd.to-match_x/
```

My bash version is: `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: I could use simpler regex ```'\(.*/[aA][nN][dD][rR][oO][iI][dD][^/]*/\)'```, but this is not the point of my question.

Comment: The capturing group `( )` is whole regex. So it will return whole string. Put only what you want to have captured in parentheses eg. `'\.*/[wW][oO][rR][dD]([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]*)/\'`.

Comment: If `-` isn't escaped, it has to be the first or last character in the bracket expression; otherwise, you are defining a range starting with `_` and ending with `.`, which is empty because `_` comes *after* `.` in ASCII.

Comment: There should really not be situations where you use `expr` in Bash. It's a useful crutch if you are stuck in a legacy shell but Bash has built-in functionality which by and large makes `expr`  superfluous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dot is not the problem. All characters inside a bracket expression are treated literally... except `-`.

Your trailing 3 characters, `_-.`, define a range consisting of (in ASCII order) the characters starting with `_` and ending with `.`. Since `_` is ASCII 95 and `.` is ASCII 46, the range is empty, so your regular expression is equivalent to `'\(.*/[wW][oO][rR][dD][a-zA-Z0-9]*/\)'`.

When you moved `.` to the left, `-` becomes the last character in the bracket expression, so it is now treated literally rather than part of a range definition, and so each of `.`, `_`, and `-` were included as part of the bracket expression.

As an aside, you don't need to use `expr` for regular expression matching in `bash`.

```
regex='(.*/[wW][oO][rR][dD][[:alnum:]_.-]*/)'
[[ $str =~ $regex ]]
echo "match: ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Comment: In a character class (bracket expression), not only is `-` special but `^` at the start is special, and so is `]` as the first character (after the `^` if present).  If you want a character class to match anything except `]` and `-`, you need `[^]-]`.  This is extreme edge-case-ism (but technically, your "all characters inside a bracket expression are treated literally, except `-`" comment is an over-simplification).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. `]` was in the back of my mind when I wrote this, but I mentally shuffled that off as purely a parsing issue.